# Add "this" to click event function that also takes other arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I can always make this work (simple printing of the clicked object):

```
$("someobject").click(function() {console.log(this)});
```

and I can always make this work (inserting a pre-made function to execute on click):

```
$("someobject").click( function() {preMadeFunction(x,y,z)});
```

but how can I pass `this` as an additional argument into a pre-made function I'm inserting? I.e., the object that I've clicked on plays a part in the pre-made inner function I'm inserting, something that would have the effect of this:

```
$("someobject").click( function() {preMadeFunction(this,x,y,z)});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the `this` when you call your function using [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), where the first argument is the `this` binding you want to set for your function, and the additional arguments are the function's arguments you want to pass:

```js
function preMadeFunction(x, y, z) {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(x, y, z);
}

$(".someobject").click(function() {
  preMadeFunction.call(this, 1,2,3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someobject">A</div>
<div class="someobject">B</div>
<div class="someobject">C</div>
```

Another option could be to make `preMadeFunction` a curried function which closes over your input arguments and returns a function that then gets its `this` bounded by jQuery:

```js
function preMadeFunction(x, y, z) {
  return function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(x, y, z);
  }
}

$(".someobject").click(preMadeFunction(1, 2, 3));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someobject">A</div>
<div class="someobject">B</div>
<div class="someobject">C</div>
```

Comment: Yes, have a look at call: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call @Jonathan

Comment: Thank you! !

"The call() method calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided individually."

Literally what I was asking haha.

Comment: @nick any advantage to doing it in the latter method?

Comment: @Jonathan I can't think of any off the top of my head, it's mainly just there to show another option